# maximum of uniform (continuous) random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X_1$, ..., $X_n$ be i.i.d. uniform random variables in $[0,a]$, with $a>0$.

If $0<t<a$, I computed $P(\max_{1\leq i \leq n} X_i \leq a-t)$ : 
\begin{align*}
P(\max_{1\leq i \leq n} X_i \leq a-t) & = P(\cap_{1\leq i \leq n} \{ X_i \leq a-t\})  \\
& = \prod_{1\leq i \leq n}P(X_i \leq a-t) \\
& = \Big( \frac{t}{a}\Big)^n
\end{align*}
Is that seems right to you?

Comment: Kavi points out your mistake correctly. For yourself, if you want to check your result, just fill in some values, for example what happens if you fill in $t=a$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake was obvious indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P(X_i \leq a-t)=\frac {a-t} a=1-\frac t a$.